# QR code in Prawn (PDF Gem), use a table? or a different simple solution?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, qr-code, prawn

I've tried many gems for creating PDF documents, some of them work really well without too much difficulty. My mission is to create a QRcode in a PDF document. I've tried a lot of combinations between QR generators and PDF generators. Although I'm having a lot of trouble actually getting the Qr code into the PDF document. I'm using the `rqrcode` gem, I like it because it generates QR codes from CSS, not an image.

I've tried using gems specifically built for generating QR codes with Prawn, however I keep getting a message saying that it doesn't recognise the `modules` method. The closest I've got is by using a similar structure in my `html` document. But thats only using it without a table, which is useless because the gem works by outputting a table and CSS.

I know this is quite vague, but because of the amount of possible solutions and different attempts I've tried I'm not sure what other information I should give.

Any ideas? Has anyone else managed to create a QR code with the `rqrcode` gem using a table in Prawn?

How the table looks in the view (HTML, not PDF):

```
<table class="qr">
 <% qr.modules.each_index do |x| -%>
   <tr>
   <% qr.modules.each_index do |y| -%>
    <% if qr.dark?(x,y) -%>
    <td class="black"/>
    <% else -%>
    <td class="white"/>
    <% end -%>
   <% end -%>
   </tr>
 <% end -%>
</table>
```

The closest I've come without it breaking in the `.prawn.pdf file` (when I try to add a table it breaks). The `*` and `!` is just testing that the `modules method` works, when I try to change it to cell background it breaks.

```
@qr.modules.each_index do |x|
   @qr.modules.each_index do |y|
    if @qr.dark?(x,y)
      pdf.text "!"
    else
      pdf.text "*"
    end
   end
 end
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'prawn'

gem 'prawn-qrcode'

gem "rqrcode", "~> 0.4.2"
```

**Update**

I found some useful [code](https://gist.github.com/1791941), although now the problem I have is the actual sizing of the QR code. I want to be able to make the QR code very big. Surprisingly enough the parameters in the new code don't actually change the size; the `size` parameter inside the actual QR code does change the size very slightly, but it's actually changing the [version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Design) of the QR code, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

i had a nearly similar problem. I had a to generate a pdf document of barcodes. the barcodes needed to be displayed in a grid in the html view and when user clicks on 'save as pdf', a pdf file of the view be send to user. 
I solved it as

in controller, before class

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'barby'
require 'barby/barcode/code_128'
require 'chunky_png'
require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'
require 'aws/s3'
```

controller method

```
def generate_barcode
   ...
   @barcode_numbers = inspection.get_barcode_numbers
   ...
   @barcode_numbers.each do |d|
     barcode = Barby::Code128B.new(d)
     image_path = get_image_path + "code_#{params[:inspection_id]}_#{@spec.id}_#{d.sub('.', '0')}.png"
     File.open(image_path, 'w'){|f|
       f.write barcode.to_png(:height => 50, :margin => 3)
       Barcode.create(:filename => "code_#{params[:inspection_id]}_#{@spec.id}_#{d.sub('.', '0')}.png", :measurement => d)
     }
   end
   html = render_to_string(:action => "generate_barcode.html.haml", :layout => false)
   kit = PDFKit.new(html)
   send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'barcodes.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
   @all_barcodes.each do |d|
     File.delete("#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{d.filename}")
   end if Rails.env != "development"
   @all_barcodes.destroy_all
```

Comment: Looks good. Although I don't want to store the QR code as an image, even if I'm deleting the image straight afterwards. I found some code that uses barby (I updated my question). But I'm having problems with increasing the size of the QR code. I see that you used barby in your answer. Have you had any experience with sizing with barby?

Comment: i have generated the barcode image of size 50. its in the above code. i think u can generate QRCode using barby too.

Comment: It seems that its not possible with the method I am currently using. The height method is not recognised for the QRcode. I'll vote your answer up because you definitely deserve points but for now I'm holding out to try and find a way to do this without the use of images. I might try a table again if I don't find an answer with my current setup, or I might use your method, in which case I'll tick it correct. But until then I really want something without images, or at least not uploading or downloading images. :)